# category title and description in multi language issue

Tags: multi-language

[image]

How to change the category title and description in multi language? Plz help me anyone.. 
I have installed this plugin :  mLanguage Version 1.6.1!

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFhIK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `[de]Deutsch title here[/de][en]English title here[/en]` in the name field?

(obviously [de] is for German language, replace these with the desired language codes)

Comment: thanks for ur response. Actuly I need Malay language for that I used [ms] tag. but its not working... Please check the screenshot..

Comment: Have you tried <span class="ms">Malay Description</span>?

Comment: Yeah, I tried. actuly I have attached screenshot here...